# How to put a method into single function

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

How can I put the method into a single Jquery function?

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    width: "100%",
    height: $(window).height() * 0.9,
    filtering: true,
    sorting: true,
    autoload: true,
    controller: db,
    fields: [
        { name: "ID", type: "number", width: "100px"},
        { name: "name", type: "text", width: "150px"},
        { name: "Status", type: "text", width: "100px"}
    ],
});
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid("sort", { field: "ID", order: "desc" });
```

I would like to put "sort" into the upper function, because I don't want to trigger this twice.

Comment: I think you can write it like `$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({...}).jsGrid("sort", { field: "ID", order: "desc" });` if this is what you are asking about. But still, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As the first function is going to display the information in a table
and the second function will do the sorting, I just want to make it simple to do all in one go